# Loop through hours vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two strings with dates, I want to loop through the hours of the dates. I tried the following:

```
strStart = "15-01-2016 09:00"
strEnd = "16-01-2016 15:00"
j=0

for i = cdate(strStart) to cdate(strEnd)
    msgbox(i)
    j=j+1
next i
```

I also tried replacing `cdate()` in the for loop by `timevalue()`. At the end, I want my `j` to be 30. (15 hours of the first day and 15 of the second)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hcxe65wz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)- and [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)-Functions for this:

```
dateStart = cDate(strStart)
dateEnd = cDate(strEnd)
j = 0
While DateDiff("h", dateStart, dateEnd) > 0
    j=j+1
    dateStart = DateAdd("h", 1, dateStart)
Wend
```

This way, you don't have to create a new `Date` for every loop, and you can easily access other date formats (days, minutes, years...)

Comment: Works fine, but for me it doesn't actually work when it has to go to the next day. Any easy way to solve this?

Comment: I just corrected a small typo in `strStart`, please make sure your dates are set up correctly. Besides that, what do you mean by "has to go to the next day"? Does it behave strangely as soon as `startDate` hits midnight?

Comment: It begins acting strange when it's 15:00 on the first day, maybe because the hour part of the date isn't different anymore?

Comment: I can't reproduce that...Please doublecheck if the days of the dates are actually different. Also, make sure your local Time Format isn't confusing days and months!